# Prove that the solution to $x'=x+\epsilon \sin(x)$ converges uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am asked to prove that the $2\pi$-periodic solution to the equation $x'=-x+\epsilon \sin(x)$ converges uniformly to zero as $\epsilon \to 0$.

I proved in a previous exercise that there is a $2\pi$-periodic solution to the equation such that $(0)∈[−2,2]$.

I have also proved (following a hint) that since $x' < 0$ if $x > 2|\epsilon|$ and $x'>0$ if $x < 2 |\epsilon|$ then every solution $y(t)$ such that there exist $t_0$ with $y(t_0) \in [-2|\epsilon|, 2|\epsilon|]$ must satisfy $|y(t)| \leq 2|\epsilon|$ in all the domain, so uniform convergence is ensured for these types of solutions.

How can I go on to show uniform convergence in the general case?

Comment: What solution over what domain is considered? With $-x-ϵ\le x'\le -x+ϵ$ one gets $-ϵ+x(0)e^{-t}\le x(t)\le ϵ+x(0)e^{-t}$. Depending on $x(0)$ this is far away from zero for fixed $t$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I just need to prove that the $2 \pi$-periodic solution to the problem converges uniformly, I had misunderstood the problem. I proved in a previous exercise that there is a solution to the equation such that $x(0) \in [-2,2]$ that was $2 \pi$-periodic. It is for that solution that I have to prove uniform convergence.

Comment: Is the DE then correct? For periodic solutions I would expect $x'=-x+ϵ\sin(t)$. Then if $u_1$ is the solution for $ϵ=1$, then $u_ϵ=ϵu_1$ is the solution for general $ϵ$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann You are right. And since $u_1$ is bounded the sequence $\epsilon u_1$ converges to $0$ uniformly as $\epsilon \to 0$, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $x_\epsilon$ a $2\pi$-periodic solution (forget about questions of uniqueness since the initial value is not specified) to $x' = -x + \epsilon \sin(x)$. you can represent the solution by
$$x_\epsilon(t) = e^{-t} x_\epsilon(0) + e^{-t} \int_0^t \epsilon e^s \sin(x_\epsilon(s)) \, ds.$$ In light of periodicity you also have $$x_\epsilon(t) = x_\epsilon(t + 2n\pi) = e^{-t - 2n\pi} x_\epsilon(0) +  e^{-t-2n\pi} \int_0^{t+2n\pi} \epsilon e^s \sin(x_\epsilon(s)) \, ds$$ for all integers $n$. Let $t \in [0,2\pi]$. Then
$$|e^{-t - 2n\pi} x_\epsilon(0)| \le e^{-2n\pi}|x_\epsilon(0)|$$ and
$$ \left| \int_0^{t+2n\pi} \epsilon e^s \sin(x_\epsilon(s)) \, ds \right| \le \epsilon e^{-t-2n\pi} \int_0^{t + 2n\pi} e^s \, ds < \epsilon.$$ This leads to $$|x_\epsilon(t)| < e^{-2n\pi} |x_\epsilon(0)| + \epsilon$$ for all $t \in [0,2\pi]$.  Since $n$ was arbitrary you can let $n \to \infty$ to conclude that $|x_\epsilon(t)| \le \epsilon$ for all $t \in [0,2\pi]$ and by periodicity all $t$. This gives you uniform convergence and really restricts what initial values are permitted.

Comment: Where does that representation come from? I am familiar with: $x(t) = x(0) + \int^t_{t_0} f(s,x(s)) ds$ that in this case would be: $x(t) = x(0) + \int^t_0 x(s) + \epsilon \sin(x(s)) ds$. Are you applying some kind of integrating factor?

Comment: If $$[e^t x(t)]' = e^t x'(t) + e^t x(t) = \epsilon e^t \sin(x(t))$$
then $$e^t x(t) = x(0) + \int_0^t \epsilon e^s \sin(x(s)) \, ds$$ by the fundamental theorem.

Comment: $x'=−x+ϵ\sin(x)$ does not have periodic solutions except trivially the constant ones. As autonomous scalar DE, all other solutions are strictly monotonous.